# Kotlin - Setting background colour for transparent PNG in ImageView

Tags: android, kotlin, imageview

I have an ImageView that has a drawable as its background.

This is how I attempted to do it:

```
imageView.background = drawable             
imageView.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#hexCode"))
```

The PNG is displayed, but the background colour isn't. What's the proper way to do it?

Expected output:

[image: expected]

Actual output:

[image: actual]

Answer (score 0):

This is a work around
Create another drawable and set the background color to the grey color

Create two imageviews with the same constraint and set the image resource of the first to the drawable and the second to the transparent imageview

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).